# Masking credentials appeared as part of a pipeline task execution logs in an ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, yaml

I'm trying to find a way to mask the credentials being passed in a command when executing the below tasks in case there is an execution failure,

```
- name: Define string variables for username and password
  set_fact:
    temp_user: "{{ user }}"
    temp_pass: "{{ password }}"

- name: run-script
  command: "{{ abc }} {{ def }}/ghi/jkl.js {{ temp_user }} {{ 
               temp_pass }} {{ mno }} {{ pqr }}"
  no_log: true
  register: output
  become: yes
  become_user: root
```

Firstly, I tried using fact "no_log" but it hides the command in logs and only refers that there is an execution failure without any additional details which is not desired, The required approach is to view the log but with masked credentials so trying the below,

```
- name: Define string variables for username and password
  set_fact:
    temp_user: "{{ user }}"
    temp_pass: "{{ password }}"

- name: run-script
  command: "{{ abc }} {{ def }}/ghi/jkl.js {{ temp_user }} {{ 
               temp_pass }} {{ mno }} {{ pqr }}"
  ignore_errors: True
  no_log: true
  register: output
  become: yes
  become_user: root

- debug:
    msg: "{{ output.stderr | regex_replace(temp_user, '*****') | 
             regex_replace(temp_pass, '*****') }}"
  when: output.stderr != ""

- debug:
    msg: "{{ output.stdout | regex_replace(temp_user, '*****') | 
             regex_replace(temp_pass, '*****') }}"
  when: output.stdout != ""
```

I used the facts "no_log" & "ignore_erros" followed by the "debug" module to hide the command when there is a failure and also view a level of debugging info with replacing credentials with asterisks so that it cannot be exposed but this approach doesn't output the desired level of debugging, Is there a better approach to mask the credentials in logs when there is a failure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the below approach and it works,

```
- name: run-script
  command: "{{ abc }} {{ def }}/ghi/jkl.js {{ user }} {{ pass }} {{ mno }} {{ 
               pqr }}"
  no_log: true
  register: output
  become: yes
  become_user: root

- name: debug error
  debug:
    msg: "{{ output | replace(rhsso_user, '*****') | replace(rhsso_password, 
             '*****') }}"
  when: output.stderr != ""
  
- name: debug output
  debug:
    msg: "{{ output | replace(rhsso_user, '*****') | replace(rhsso_password, 
             '*****') }}"
  when: output.stdout != ""
```